# Reading a JSON text file with headers and retrieving only the data under a specified header into a variable in Python

Tags: python, json

I have a text file with json and known header names.

Example:

```
[header0]
{
  "IPMI": {
      "ProtocolEnabled": true,
      "Port": 623
  },
  "SSH": {
      "ProtocolEnabled": true,
      "Port": 22
  }
}
[header1]
{
  "GraphicalConsole": {
      "ServiceEnabled": true,
      "MaxConcurrentSessions": 2
  }
}
[header2]
{
  "InterfaceEnabled": true,
  "SignalType": "Rs232",
  "BitRate": "115200",
  "Parity": "None",
  "DataBits": "8",
  "StopBits": "1"
}
```

I am trying to create a variable (payload) with the json under a specific header to use with the requests module. I can iterate and print the data with a loop with no issues.

```
with open("test.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('[header1]'):  # beginning of section use first line
            for line in f:  # check for end of section breaking if we find the stop line
                if line.startswith("[header2]"):
                    break
                else:  # else process lines from section
                    print(line.rstrip("\n"))
```

Which outputs:

```
{
  "GraphicalConsole": {
      "ServiceEnabled": true,
      "MaxConcurrentSessions": 2
  }
}
```

This is perfect but how would I create a variable with the same data?

Comment: The best thing to do is build a dictionary where the keys are header0, header1 etc. Then, for each key, have a value that's a list and append each line within a header/section to that list. Subsequently, you'll be able to easily access all lines within a header/section by key

Comment: I updated my question to show actual JSON data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want a list of the lines you need then create an empty list and add each relevant line

```
with open("test.txt") as f:
reslist = []
for line in f:
    if line.startswith('[header1]'):  # beginning of section use first line
        for line in f:  # check for end of section breaking if we find the stop line
            if line.startswith("[header2]"):
                break
            else:  # else process lines from section
                print(line.rstrip("\n"))
                reslist.append(line)
return reslist
```

if you want to output a string you could do...

```
resstring = '\n'.join(reslist)
```

see 'DarkKnight's comment above if you want to collect output from each header in a dict

Comment: I am actually trying to return the data the same way as it prints in my example. The data will actually be JSON code, and I will be using it as a payload for requests and each header will be a separate JSON payload.

Comment: have a look at the json module - you can turn the resulting list into a JSON object using json.dump (or a string using json.dumps) so `payload = json.dump(resstring)`. if you want to return a key:value pair you could go `payload = json.dump({'[headerX]': resstring})`

Comment: Yes I use the json module extensively. What I am trying to solve is exporting json data from a HP iLO using redfish. There will be around 20 different json sections to manage per firmware version. I would like to have a single file per firmware version with 20 headers instead of managing 20 separate files per firmware version which would be insane.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:-

```
import json

def main(filename):
    payload = {}
    ch = None
    jt = []
    with open(filename) as txt:
        for line in txt.readlines():
            if line.startswith('['):
                if ch and jt:
                    payload[ch] = json.loads(''.join(jt))
                    jt = []
                ch = line[1:line.index(']')]
            else:
                jt.append(line.strip())
        if ch and jt:
            payload[ch]=json.loads(''.join(jt))
    print(json.dumps(payload, indent=4))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main('test.txt')
```